# SQL: What is the best way to select rows from a table that do not exist in another table only with a particular id?

Tags: sql, informix

I use the Informix database where I have 2 tables **artind** and **coord** that have relationship with one another, **key_code** and **cm_key_coord_code**

table **artind**

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Field     | Type        |
+-----------+-------------+
| key_code  | char(8)     |
| descr     | char(30)    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

table **coord**

```
+--------------------+-------------+
| Field              | Type        |
+--------------------+-------------+
| cm_key_coord_code  | char(8)     |
| cm_t_coor          | int         |
| descr_coord        | char(30)    |
+--------------------+-------------+
```

Usually to select all record in table artind that not have a record with
same code (  key_code equal to cm_key_coord_code ) and cm_t_coor = 2 in
table coord I use:

```
select * from artind where
key_code not in (select cm_key_coord_code from coord
where cm_t_coor = 2);
```

There is a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is fine, but not recommended.  If any `cm_key_coord_code` values are `NULL`, then no records will be selected.  That is how `NOT IN` is defined, but not usually what is intended.

I advise either `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select a.*
from artind a
where not exists (select 1
                  from coord c
                  where c.cm_t_coor = 2 and c.cm_key_coord_code = a.key_code
                 );
```

or:

```
select a.*
from artind a left join
     coord c
     on c.cm_t_coor = 2 and c.cm_key_coord_code = a.key_code
where c.cm_key_coord_code is null;
```

Comment: In table coord I have multiple record with same cm_key_coord_code, but different cm_t_coor. How can I select cm_key_coord_code that have only rows with  cm_t_coor != 2 ?

Comment: @famedoro . . . That is subtly different from the question you asked.  I would suggest that you ask another question, with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640610/sql-how-can-i-select-only-one-record-which-non-present-an-id

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is a better way than yours. i can give you a different one, but ultimately this will likely be translated to the same operations from the query-engine. you query actually might be more performant.

```
select artind.* from artind 
    left join coord on key_code = cm_key_coord_code and cm_t_coor = 2 
where cm_key_coord_code is null
```

if you have performance problems with yours i suggest looking at the indexes on the tables