# Sql: How can I select only one record which non present an id

Tags: sql, select, informix

I use the Informix database where I have a table **coord** :

```
+--------------------+-------------+
| Field              | Type        |
+--------------------+-------------+
| cm_key_coord_code  | char(8)     |
| cm_t_coor          | int         |
| descr_coord        | char(30)    |
+--------------------+-------------+
```

which contains data such as those shown below:

```
+-cm_key_coord_code-+-cm_t_coor-+-descr_coord-+
+ 00000001          +    1      + coord01a    +
+ 00000001          +    2      + coord01b    +
+ 00000002          +    1      + coord02a    +
+ 00000002          +    2      + coord02b    +
+ 00000003          +    1      + coord03a    +
+ 00000004          +    2      + coord04a    +
+ 00000005          +    1      + coord05a    +
+-------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

The table has multiple record with same cm_key_coord_code, but different cm_t_coor. How can I select cm_key_coord_code that have only rows with cm_t_coor != 2 ?

I want to select only the following values:

```
+-cm_key_coord_code-+-cm_t_coor-+-descr_coord-+
+ 00000003          +    1      + coord03a    +
+ 00000005          +    1      + coord05a    +
+-------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Using a Ranking functions could be a solution

Comment: @Vijey Could you give me an example ?

Comment: What if there are two rows with a certain cm_key_coord_code but for one cm_t_coor = 1 and for the other, cm_t_coor = 3? Should one or both or neither rows be returned?

Comment: @kbball both rows with cm_t_coor = 1 and cm_t_coor = 3 should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM Table t1,
       ( SELECT cm_key_coord_code
           FROM Table
         GROUP BY cm_key_coord_code   
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 1      
        ) t2
 WHERE t1.cm_key_coord_code = t2.cm_key_coord_code
   AND t1.cm_t_coor <> 2;
```

Comment: What if there are two rows with a certain cm_key_coord_code but for one cm_t_coor = 1 and for the other, cm_t_coor = 3? Then your answer wouldn't return those rows, but I think they should be returned

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select c.cm_key_coord_code
from coord c
group by c.cm_key_coord_code
having sum(case when c.cm_t_coor = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

You can get the original rows in one of two ways.  One method is to join the results together or (equivalently) using `in` or `exists`:

```
select c.*
from coord c
where c.cm_key_coord_code in (select c.cm_key_coord_code
                              from coord c
                              group by c.cm_key_coord_code
                              having sum(case when c.cm_t_coor = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                             );
```

Alternatively, if you know there is always only one row, you can use aggregation functions:

```
select c.cm_key_coord_code, min(cm_t_coor), min(descr_coord)
from coord c
group by c.cm_key_coord_code
having sum(case when c.cm_t_coor = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: @Teja You probably should add more information on what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a NOT EXISTS clause as well. Try:

```
SELECT c.cm_key_coord_code
FROM coord c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM coord c2
 WHERE c2.cm_key_coord_code = c.cm_key_coord_code
 AND c2.cm_t_coor = 2)
```